# Issue with splitting csv file

Tags: stanford-nlp

When I run a csv file of tweets through the CoreNLP command line, it splits the tweets based on where periods are in the tweets.  I want one output for every line of the csv file, but that is not always the case.  How do I split csv files in the CoreNLP command line?  This is the same for txt files as well.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

CoreNLP does not currently support processing CSV files. However, it does support one sentence per-line files, which is the same as the special case of a one column CSV file. To process these without any splitting of sentences, use: `-ssplit.eolonly true`

Comment: Thank you very much!